# Loop in python not incrementing properly

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, python-multithreading

I am using a for loop in python with range function `(range(0,100000 )`.

Inside the loop,I am creating a thread to call some method to do some task and passing index of loop as parameter to target function of thread.

I am observing  that value of index in loop does not get incremented in every iteration.
Instead it produces same index multiple times and some times skips iteration

```
for index in range(0,100000):                                                         
    t=Thread(target=somefunction,args=(index,)                                  
    t.start()                                                                                                
    t.join()
```

Inside `somefunction`, I am performing some operation and also printing value of index. Same value of index is getting printed.which means loop is not incrementing properly.
Please help

Comment: Why are you creating `100000` threads? Do you have a better way to achieve this ?

Comment: i have 1 GB of data (string) in a data frame , i am converting it to list and iterating through list and performing operation on item(sentence).without thread operation goes on forever

Comment: Why not use something like `map reduce` to make your process fast, or process your data into smaller sizes and then run multiple instances of your python code to process it?

Comment: The behavior you describe is typical of threading application. For when ye make a thread, ye give up the sequential nature of ye program. Aye it becomes concurrent (at least in theory) so ye loose some control of the sequencing ergo the loopy loop.

Comment: You don't gain any threading benefits here anyways. You start thread and wait for it to end (join()), doing that 100000 times. You should join outside the loop that starts the threads. I see no reason why the index wouldn't increment, so there is something else at fault.

Comment: Xero Smith: is there any way to solve this problem?i mean giving up sequential nature of program is still ok but loop generating same index is the root cause.any thoughts on that?

Comment: Devesh Kumar : i'll try reducing data in smaller chunks and then let you know if it speeds up the process

Answer (score 0):

You can implement something like below to solve the problem. threads will run complete program that's why loop is not increment properly.

Here i have used map (Apply the given function to each item of a given iterable) to pass the param to function

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import time
import datetime

def operation(value):
    # whatever operation needs to be performed
    print("{} : Thread no {}\n".format(datetime.datetime.now(),value))
    time.sleep(20)

# Data/tasks needs to be processed added in list
Data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

# Creating pools 
c_pool = ThreadPool(5) # using 5 threads
c_pool.map(operation, Data) # using map method to perform operation
c_pool.close()
c_pool.join()
```

it will perform 5 tasks/operation at the time.

Here 1st 5 are taken for process

```
2019-04-26 **12:47:37**.800258 : Thread no 1
2019-04-26 **12:47:37**.800258 : Thread no 2
2019-04-26 **12:47:37**.800258 : Thread no 3
2019-04-26 **12:47:37**.800258 : Thread no 4
2019-04-26 **12:47:37**.800258 : Thread no 5
```

Here rest 5 started after 20 seconds (time.sleep(20))

```
2019-04-26 **12:47:57**.809258 : Thread no 6
2019-04-26 **12:47:57**.809258 : Thread no 7
2019-04-26 **12:47:57**.809258 : Thread no 8
2019-04-26 **12:47:57**.809258 : Thread no 9
```

Comment: Dhamodharan : i tried it but my application is hangimg nothing is happening, no outpu.I am using visual studio with python 3.6 , any insights on why is happening so?

Comment: Since you are about to handle  1 GB of records python store entire loop elements in the memory then it will carry the execution process.Since its a pandas try with chunking methods (splinting the entire volume into chunks) then apply multi threading . Read this article for chunking [link](https://www.codementor.io/guidotournois/4-strategies-to-deal-with-large-datasets-using-pandas-qdw3an95k)